# Angular unit test cases failing in a random manner

Tags: angular, unit-testing, npm, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit test cases for my angular 11 project. It was all running fine, but suddenly some test cases wont pass. It would show random errors, but would pass later on (may not too). It would show errors like `Cannot read property 'triggerEventHandler' of null` or `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` or some other errors. But after re-running `ng test` again and again, it would pass at some point. What should I do? I tried `npm cache clean --force` command. It let me work for a day. But again it started behaving the same. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mock the services you use in the component you are testing.

You can try adding in the describe block:
`let serviceMock: SpyObj<ServiceClass>;`

Add in the beforeEach:
`serviceMock = createSpyObj('ServiceClass', ['methodName']);`

and in the providers list:
`{ provide: ServiceClass, useValue: serviceMock }`

Then you can decide if you need to mock the returning value of that method or just return NEVER.

e.g. `serviceMock.methodName.and.returnValue(NEVER);`